# Angular Drag and Drop - DropList that was display none, will not recieve items even after setting to display block

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk

My requirements call for hiding the `cdkDropList` until the user starts to drag an item. So when the user starts to drag an item, the drop lists get visible, and they will start to receive them.

I achieve it by setting display none in the CSS as below.

```
.drop {
  display: block;
}


// this makes the drop element display: none until you start dragging (angular adds the class .cdk-drop-list-dragging when drag is started)

.drop(:not(.cdk-drop-list-receiving):not(.cdk-drop-list-dragging)) {
  display: none;
}
```

However, this does not work, and the `cdkDropList` elements will not receive my items.

If I remove `display: none;` and do instead `visibility: hidden;` it will work. The problem is that I need it to not take out space in the DOM. (I tried all approaches like position: absolute, and anything that moves/removes the element will prevent this from being dropable once displayed).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you set the width and height to 0 before drag and drop start? It is still in the DOM but takes not place.

Comment: Same issue. Looks like this issue is that the dom freezes in terms of dropping. so if width and height is 0 there is nowhere do dop to